# How to access a DataGrid created on a different thread in a UI thread?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface

Over the forum and on MSDN they have given a clear way to access the UI controls from different thread using Dispatcher.Invoke. But, when in UI thread, how do I access a WPF component ex DataGrid created on a different thread ?

In my situation, I start a thread to handle a long process. In this thread I create a DataTable, and bind it to a DataGrid which is also created in this thread.

Now, when it is time to display the DataGrid, I appropriately call the Dispatcher.Invoke on a UI control. But, when I try to access the DataGrid in my UI thread, I get an exception -The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Any suggestion please ..

```
public void AddResultsController(ResultsController controller)
{
  NewResultsControllerDisplayDelegate newControllerDisplayDelegate = new NewResultsControllerDisplayDelegate(NewResultsControllerDisplay);
  this.docManager.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(newControllerDisplayDelegate, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, controller);
}

delegate void NewResultsControllerDisplayDelegate(ResultsController controller);
private void NewResultsControllerDisplay(ResultsController controller)
{
   Grid grd = new Grid();
   grd.Children.Add(controller.SummaryDataGrid);   // Exception is thrown here
}
```

In my background thread I call...

```
m_mainWindow.AddResultsController(m_controller);
```

Comment: I suppose using Dispatcher.Invoke() is right approach.

Can you post your code?

Comment: Please help ...I'm stuck and unable to proceed further.

Comment: Grid grd = new Grid();
grd.Children.Add(controller.SummaryDataGrid); 

I suppose you make grd in the m_mainWindow thread, but try to update it in main thread, the exception occurs at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply **do not** create UI-elements on background threads. Make your life easier and follow that rule.

Comment: This is what I landed up doing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
public void AddResultsController(ResultsController controller)
{
  NewResultsControllerDisplayDelegate newControllerDisplayDelegate = new NewResultsControllerDisplayDelegate(NewResultsControllerDisplay);
   Grid grd = new Grid();
   grd.Children.Add(controller.SummaryDataGrid); 
  this.docManager.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(newControllerDisplayDelegate, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, grd);
}

delegate void NewResultsControllerDisplayDelegate(ResultsController controller);
private void NewResultsControllerDisplay(Grid grd)
{
   this.docManager.Add(grd);
}
```

Hth.

Comment: Get this error message - The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: I wonder about controller.SummaryDataGrid, is it a usercontrol or data?

If it's a usercontrol, then which thread does it belong to?

Comment: SummaryDataGrid is a DataGrid created in the background worker thread. It is assigned a DataTable at runtime